# How to programmatically generate code to display in jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript, code-generation, jsfiddle

My goal is to generate dynamic code based on the user input, and then have that code programmatically put to jsfiddle so the user can preview the generated code as well as the running result.

I've tried using the [jsfiddler](https://github.com/Like-Falling-Leaves/jsfiddler) library which utilizes phantomjs for the job, but the only output I am getting is:

`Failed to create JS Fiddle Failed with code: Error: spawn /Users/***/test/untitled folder/untitled folder/jsfiddler/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs ENOENT`

Here is my javascript code:

```
var jsfiddler = require("./jsfiddler");

let options = {
  html: "<body>This is an example jsfiddle</body>",
  js: 'console.log("Example JS!")',
  css: "body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }",
  link: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  script: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
  title: "JSFiddler Sample",
  description: "Sample page created via JSFiddler api module",
  normalize_css: true,
  wrap: "b" /* body */,
  dtd: 4,
};
jsfiddler.create(options, function (err, fiddlerUrl) {
  if (err) return console.error("Failed to create JS Fiddle", err);
  console.log("Created JS Fiddle: ", fiddlerUrl);
});
```

It will also be super helpful if there's any other way to achieve the goal, thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: check phantomjs version by ```phantomjs --version```

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit npm phantomjs --version
7.11.2

Comment: The official documentation suggests https://phantomjs.org/ as a dependency. the latest version is 2.1.1. You might have commented the npm version

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit thanks, I managed to fix the path issue by copying the phantom package inside my project, and now it is outputting a lot more errors lol

Comment: can you show errors ?

Comment: ```node:internal/child_process:415
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^
Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:415:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:609:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shuaiqisun/333444/untitled folder/untitled folder/node_modules/jsfiddler/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)

```

Comment: remove node-modules and lock diles and npm install again and run the file

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit after removing the node_modules folder I get ```ReferenceError: node_modules is not defined``` the npm install command installed everything to /usr/myUserName/

Comment: do npm install again

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit I added a package.json file with 
```{
  "dependencies": {
    "jsfiddler": "^0.0.3"
  }
}
```
and now `npm install` works as expected, but I get the same output ```Failed to create JS Fiddle Failed with code: Error: spawn /Users/***/test/untitled folder/untitled folder/jsfiddler/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs ENOENT

```

Comment: what is the error now ?

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit `Failed to create JS Fiddle Failed with code: Error: spawn /Users/myUserName/333444/untitled folder/untitled folder/node_modules/jsfiddler/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs ENOENT
`

It is strange that jsfiddler looks into a nonexistent 'node_modules' folder inside of itself

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but for me ```npm install jsfiddler``` is showing erros.

Comment: lol, the library is last updated 7 years ago, maybe it's no longer usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to display a fiddle that's not saved in JSFiddle, using a POST.

**API Documentation**

```
https://docs.jsfiddle.net/api/display-a-fiddle-from-post
```

**Example using form**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/3Lwgk4c5/
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! I'll definitely check this out

Answer (score 1):

Well, the library is using the older version of phantomjs which is no longer configurable. Also, the installation of the package is no longer working. So, you need to figure out some other solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, it looks like neither Codepen nor Js fiddle provides the ability to display programmatically generated code :(